# Why aren't telnet and nmap reflecting the ports I closed for an ec2 security group?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, telnet

For the security group on my ec2 server (ubuntu 12.04) I opened only tcp ports 80 and 22.  I was able to access my website from the browser as well as ssh into the server.

I then deleted port 80 from the security group and saved.  I am no longer able to access my website from the broswer.

However when I run this command

```
nmap -p 80 127.0.0.1

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2012-09-23 04:29 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000067s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http
```

and this

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
```

They indicate port 80 is open, even though it's been deleted from the ec2 security group and I can no longer access the website.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know ec2 security group setting is independant of instance-wise firewall rules. Think of the ec2 security group as a firewall layer on top of the firewall of your ec2 instance. So a port is reachable **if and only if** security group has it open *and* firewall inside your instance is not blocking that port. Either layer's blocking on port will make the port unreachable.

Comment: I guess the question is other way around: what if a user wants to close port 80? It is not set in security group, therefore it means port 80 shouldn't be reached. However, why can nmap still detect port 80?